# can multiple regression be applied when all variables are nomina binary dichotomoir.. ONE DV Y/N; 3 IV Y/N

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, binary-data, excel

Can multiple regression be applied when all variables are nominal dichotomous?

Dependent variable: Y/N (binary)

3 Independent variables: Y/N (binary)

Comment: I edited the question to tidy it up. Please make sure it still has the same meaning (I think so, but that's your call).

Answer (score 1):

This would be an excellent situation to use a generalized linear model like logistic regression, since the outcome is binary. In the case where the outcome is continuous (perhaps with some other conditions), linear regression would be viable.

A key takeaway is that binary predictor variables present **no challenge** to linear and generalized linear models.

Comment: If the outcome is binary, you can still apply regression. (The question doesn't ask if it's a good idea.)

Comment: @NickCox I have tried reading about linear probability models and even have heard that they are in vogue in econometrics literature. I still do not know what to do when I get a predicted probability of $2$ (though this gets at the "good idea" part of your comment).

Comment: Naturally I am aware that predicted outcomes from linear probability models can fail to be possible.  The same can happen with plain or vanilla regression and non-binary outcomes.